# How can I tell autogen.sh to generate files(m4 and object files) in separate folder?

Tags: c, unix, makefile, autotools

I am using `./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/` to build a c [project](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~elementary-os/elementaryos/os-patch-ido-trusty/files) and all files created by the configuration process (and later the compiling and linking steps) are located in my source folder.

I would like to tell to use a different folder (say `./build` like cmake projects usually do).

How can I do that?

Is there a command line parameter? Should I change a file?

> Note: autogen.sh calls `gnome-autogen.sh`

**edit**

Trying `cd build && ../autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/` fails with the error:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-autogen.sh: ./configure: not found
```

Comment: Maybe `mkdir build && cd build && ../autogen.sh` ?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Question updated

Comment: You can see `autogen`'s help. Maybe `./autogen.sh --help` will work.

Comment: Are you putting `gnome-autogen.sh` on the `autogen.sh` command line manually? Are you supposed to? (Unless you have a specific reason using `--prefix=/usr` is a bad idea as it will cause your compiled software to conflict with packaged software.)

Comment: Comically the --help launches the configure process creating a bunch of files. While not providing the option that I'm looking for.

Comment: @EtanReisner No I just launched the autogen.sh script provided by the project (linked in the question). As for the prefix, I noticed that sometimes not setting it causes issue when testing the compiled app. For now the conflicts are not the main issue (but I'm all ears about good practice)

Comment: If `configure` cannot be found you can add it to PATH and delete after building. It may be risky, though.

Comment: @ForceBru That's not going to help with finding `./configure` unfortunately.

Comment: @Nameiscarl So what is `/usr/bin/gnome-autogen.sh` doing on that command line above? Typo? You could try setting the `NOCONFIGURE` environment variable to something non-empty before running `autogen.sh` to try to keep `gnome-autogen.sh` from running it automatically. That should let you run it by hand correctly afterwards.

Comment: Why not try to use `--srcdir=DIR` ? DIR is a source directory, where source files are located.

Comment: @EtanReisner it was a typo thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible as far as I know. `autogen` is a strange beast; the files it creates are necessary to build the project (`configure` and `Makefile.am`).

That means `autogen` is more part of the "unpack sources" than the "compile source code into product" step. After you have run `autogen`, you can run `configure` in the build directory to get a version of all files necessary to drive the build (`config.h`, `Makefile`, ...) for your specific architecture:

```
./autogen.sh
mkdir build
../configure --prefix=/usr
```

See `Compiling For Multiple Architectures` in the file `INSTALL`.

Comment: They are necessary to the build files... all of which should retain the correct relative paths/etc. in a build directory even done this way. I believe this is supposed to work with properly written `autogen.sh` scripts. And a quick search online finds a number of projects fixing things in their `autogen.sh` scripts to handle this case.

Comment: For some reason, running `./autogen.sh` also runs ./configure. Is it related to the script that ships with the project?

Comment: In my copy, it tries to run `$srcdir/configure`. Try `cd build ; srcdir=.. ../autogen.sh`. This odd syntax defines the variable `srcdir`, assigns `..` (= parent folder) to it and then runs `../autogen.sh`.

Comment: There is also a `NOCONFIGURE` variable which you could set to anything to skip the configure process. Afterwards, you can run the script yourself as in my answer.

Comment: This `NOCONFIGURE` variable seems to be common in many packages, is its usage documented anywhere?

Comment: @lanoxx I just see the feature request https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/227 and then the commit which added the feature which just changes autogen.sh but not the docs: https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/commit/11f0f5b8b781b890821d8940139e0cc2aa7e271f